# How to avoid installing unnecessary dependencies with MacPorts?

Tags: macos, dependencies, macports

I've tried to get postgresql 8.4 via MacPorts (on Snow Leopard) but it seems that the dependencies are endless - including getting older version of stuff that is already available in Snow Leopard, kitchen-sink and who knows if eventually I end up with windows 7 ...

Is there a way to get only those dependancies absolutely necessary to run stuff from command line in Mac?

Especially I'm trying to avoid installing old version of python, Xorg packages and so on.

Any ideas? So far it seems that it is better to avoid MacPorts altogether.

Comment: I'm not seeing any postgresql84 dependencies on xorg-* or py2*. Exactly what packages are you trying to install?

Comment: What variants are you loading? 0 what is the command line younare using to do install

Comment: I was using: sudo port install postgresql84 +python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [port file for postgresql84](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/databases/postgresql84/Portfile), the `+python` variant for it actually means [python2.5](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/python25/Portfile).  Most of the dependencies you find annoying are probably being brought in by the python tkinter module dependency on [Tk](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/x11/tk/Portfile) which by default builds an X11 version of Tk rather than the +quartz variant.  You can change that by specifying that variant and reinstalling.  The easy way to deal with variants is to add the options you normally want to use as defaults to those in `/opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf`.

Unfortunately, at the moment, the `tk +quartz` variant build is [broken on Snow Leopard](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/20799). So, if you are not planning to use tkinter (or IDLE) with the MacPorts python2.5, you can force the removal after the fact of the unwanted modules:

```
port installed
port -f uninstall tk Xft2 xorg-libX11 ...
```

You might want to first do a dry-run by adding the `-y` option to see exactly what the effects  of the `uninstall` will be.

Note, the `python26` port has a handy `+no_tkinter` variant which could be useful once the portgresql ports are upgraded to python2.6.

Comment: thanks for the indepth analysis, seems like for now I'll try to compile what I need by hand, if that fails I'll try MacPorts again ...

Comment: I created a ticket at MacPorts for the python variant to use python2.6. http://trac.macports.org/ticket/22075

Answer (score 5):

It's potentially a bit of grunt work (and definitely violates Occam's razor for this particular scenario)... but if you're positive you know which dependencies you don't want/need, they can always be passed as hyphen-delimited args after the port call:

```
port install sweetPort -depYouDontWant -depYouDontNeed ...
```

I know it's been a while since the OP, but I hope this helps... somebody.

Comment: This doesn't work on macports 2.3.4 ... `sudo port install ImageMagick -ghostscript` still fetches and installs ghostscript

Comment: create your own repo, modify the portfile, increase the rev, run portindex, install your version

Comment: This does not work with MacPorts 2.7.1. Installing qemu still installs python when using this command: sudo port install qemu -python310